# Onedrive does not distinguish whatsapp pictures from camera pictures in syncing

Tags: sync, onedrive, camera, backup, uploading

On my phone I have various folders: whatsapp-pictures, camera pictures, screenshots etc. When backing them up, all pictures seem to be blended in one folder 'pictures'. How can i restore the folders from my phone in onedrive? I really need this to keep them organized.

Comment: I don't think you can. I'm not sure ANY normal cloud storage (OneDrive, Dropbox, MEGA) has this functionality of per-folder backups.

Comment: You can instead use Google Photos as your photo manager and have everything be synced to your Google Drive (Google Photos) in the cloud. You'll be able to see all photos, even those that are in the cloud alone (they will automagically download as you open them on your phone)